# Make server run job on reboot of instance, from instance startup/init script

Tags: bash, cron, startup, rc.local

I want to run a python script as a user on reboot of a server.  The server itself it spun up on azure via terraform.

I've already got a startup script called `startup.sh`.  It does various things to the server that requires it to reboot.  In the script, I want to add a line that will make it do my python script *after* it reboots.  Here's how it looks now, with a placeholder for the command that I want to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

# fix cuda for azure.  for some reason their instances have cuda installed wrong and this fixes it
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-10.2 /usr/local/cuda

# pip install a few things.  TF, for instance
pip install tensorflow

# HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP:
some_command_to_make_something_run_on_next_startup --as_this_user nonRootUser --run_this_command "python myscript.py"

sudo reboot # the reboot is needed to make the cuda changes work
```

I've tried adding stuff to `/etc/rc.local`, but that didn't work.  I don't know why.  Likewise cron.  Neither of these seemed to be enabled on this freshly spun-up instance, and cron seems to be dependent on manual initiation, from what I can glean online.

The ultimate use will be to spin up swarms of servers doing the same job, so all of this needs to happen with nothing interactive.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what precisely doesn't work, and how you ensure that `some_command` is executed at the next startup (I would use the presence or absence of a file to implement that)? Also, you say that `/etc/rc.local` and `cron` are not enabled. What prevents you from enabling them?  E.g. my Ubuntu 16 server has a systemd service named `rc-local.service`. Note that I don't see how `cron` can be used to perform tasks at startup.

Comment: The instance didn't have anything at etc/rc.local when I looked there. Re cron: I just know it's a way to schedule tasks. I have never used it. All I want is some way to make a job happen after reboot. Maybe that involves enabling rc.local somehow? I don't know what I'm doing here and would appreciate some help. I don't think any of you will pretend that linux documentation is of very much pedagogic utility.